# how to catch error of async call in javascript?

Tags: javascript, grails, authorize.net, accept.js

I am integrating accept.js in my app.

https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html

This is not particularly an integration question. This is a JavaScript problem i am trying to solve.

While following the tutorial there is a function that is called when form submit is clicked. This function is responsible for packaging the credit card information and sending it asynchronously to authorize.net server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendPaymentDataToAnet() {
    var authData = {};
        authData.clientKey = "YOUR PUBLIC CLIENT KEY";
        authData.apiLoginID = "YOUR API LOGIN ID";
    var cardData = {};
        cardData.cardNumber = document.getElementById("cardNumber").value;
        cardData.month = document.getElementById("expMonth").value;
        cardData.year = document.getElementById("expYear").value;
        cardData.cardCode = document.getElementById("cardCode").value;


    var secureData = {};
        secureData.authData = authData;
        secureData.cardData = cardData;

        Accept.dispatchData(secureData, responseHandler);
}
</script>
```

The problem is Accept.dispatchData() seems to be an async call. If i disconnect the net just before clicking on submit then Accept.dispatchData will fail to connect to the external service.

It will throw the following error

[image]

My goal is to catch this error. I have tried wrapping Accept.dispatchData in try catch block but it doesnt seem to catch the error thrown. Seems like the error is caught somewhere inside it. How can i detect the ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) can be leveraged to detect `window` `errors`.

[`navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) can be used to detect `internet connection`.

```js
// Window: On Error
window.onerror = (error) => console.log('navigator.onLine:', navigator.onLine)

// Trigger.
const trigger = error
```

Comment: this is throwing "ReferenceError: error is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

This is network connection issue, if your network is down then every javascript / jquery plugin throws this exception even Google / Facebook sites. but you can check your network before calling your api as follows.

```
if(navigator.onLine){
 //do your stuff
}else{
 alert("Please, check your network connection")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.catch()`

```
Accept.dispatchData()
   .then(() => {})
   .catch( error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: i tried this but this failed. It says Cannot read property 'then' of undefined. Accept.dispatchData() seems to return undefined.